# Mapping a physical sector to a filename

Tags: filesystems, ext4

I just finished using ddrescue to recover the contents of a failing hard drive.  It was able to recover everything but two sectors.  How do I figure out which files (if any) occupied those sectors?  The filesystem in question is ext4.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/315700/how-to-determine-which-file-inode-occupies-a-given-sector